# Ограничить range slider

Tags: javascript

Не совсем получается ограничить движение маркера по слайдеру.

```js
const mark = document.getElementById('marker');
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');


mark.onmousedown = function(e) {
  let value = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - (mark.offsetWidth / 2);
 function moveAt(e) {
  mark.style.left = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - (mark.offsetWidth / 2) + 'px';
  }
 
 document.onmousemove = function (e) { 
  if(value > 0 && value < 380 ){ // value сравнивается сначала с left: 0px , потом с left: 380px, сам маркер задан абсолютным позиционированием
   moveAt(e);
   console.log(value);
  }
  else{
   console.log("Что-то сделать"); // проблема в том что else срабатывает после отпускания маркера
  } 
 }
 
 document.onmouseup = function () {
  document.onmousemove = null;
    mark.onmouseup = null;
 }
}
```

```css
#slider{
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #d5dbe5;
 margin: 30px auto;
}
#marker{
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 40px;
 background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
 <div id="marker"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы один раз вычисляете

`let value = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - (mark.offsetWidth / 2);`
и потом сравниваете это значение с ограничителями. Его надо рассчитывать каждый раз, чтоб оно было актуальным.

```js
const mark = document.getElementById('marker');
const slider = document.getElementById('slider');

mark.onmousedown = e => {
    let value = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - (mark.offsetWidth / 2);
    const moveAt = value => {
        mark.style.left = value + 'px';
    }
    document.onmousemove = e => {    
        value = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft - (mark.offsetWidth / 2);
        if(value > 0 && value < 380 ){
            moveAt(value);
        }else{
            moveAt(value>0?380:0);
        }    
    }
    document.onmouseup = () => {
        document.onmousemove = null;
        mark.onmouseup = null;
    }
}
```

```css
#slider{
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #d5dbe5;
 margin: 30px auto;
}
#marker{
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 40px;
 background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
 <div id="marker"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а как сделать заливку цветом за бегунком слайдера?